# benchmark tcp: ab or iperf like tool to send hex/binary/pcap data?

Tags: networking, tcp, benchmark, iperf

I have written a server in Twisted for a current project I'm working on, and now I need to test it. It receives TCP packets, with the payload consisting of just a serialised binary string. I want to be able to test the server for concurrency/throughput using the binary data as the payload, but can not find any tool that will allow me to do this. I tried `iperf -F` but it didn't work, as I think it was sending the binary/hex data as chars. I've also looked at `ab` which seems to be perfect - if only for http. As well as these, I've had a look at `tcpreplay`, but it doesn't perform any testing (or establish TCP connections) so it's not much use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm rather stuck on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ncat, I'm fairly certain it can do this.
http://nmap.org/ncat/

Perhaps as a file transfer?
http://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-file-transfer.html

It has a --hex-dump option so you can see whats really going on.

You could also just compile a simple program to output exactly what you want and use netcat to call that and transfer its output.